# Creating an image out of text?

Tags: android, image, imageview, fresco

I want to create an image out of some text. For example, in this photo I have shown here, I want to make it so that I have an image or some sort of text view that shows a plus sign and then I would programmatically set the number in my code in that image. Here is an example:

[image]

As you can see here. I woudl want the exact behavior: to set the `+16` as an image or some sort of text view I can programmatically set. I some XML here so that I can create an image based on a URI I pass in here:

```
        <com.facebook.drawee.view.SimpleDraweeView
            android:id="@+id/commenter_photo_four"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="60dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="60dp"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/num_comments"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@id/num_comments"
            fresco:placeholderImage="@mipmap/blank_prof_pic"
            fresco:placeholderImageScaleType="centerCrop"
            fresco:roundBottomLeft="false"
            fresco:roundBottomRight="false"
            fresco:roundedCornerRadius="5dp"
            fresco:roundingBorderColor="@color/material_color_grey_100"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            />
```

which displays the photo correctly for me. However, I can't seem to be able to insert something like `android:text` or do some sort of `setText` method when using the `Fresco` library (library I use to render my images based on a URI). Then I tried using an `ImageView` like so:

```
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/commenter_photo_four"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="60dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="60dp"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/num_comments"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@id/num_comments"
            />
```

but then I realize that this also doesn't have an `android:text` capability I can use to set the image to being a + followed by any number I would want to set. Is there any way I can accomplish this `+16`? I am also thinking I can try a `TextView` with a circular background possibly?

Answer (score 0):

You can draw text to your imageView by code

```
Bitmap b=Bitmap.createBitmap(width, width, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
Canvas c = new Canvas(b);
Paint p = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
c.drawText("+16",10,10,p);

ImageView i = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.commenter_photo_four);
i.setImageBitmap(b);
```

Comment: This works well, thanks. However, I want to set the `ImageView` background. I did something like this: `imageView.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.material_color_grey_200));` but the background looks to be it is a square after i do the `findViewById`. Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: If you want round background - draw by 
canvas.drawCircle(x, y, radius, paint); 
as grey circle. Default background in bitmap is transparent. If you set background to some color then if the bitmap is square then the background will be also square.

Answer (score 0):

you can set imageview and textview in Relative layout and set textview's visibility gone. Then when you want to put text in it set textview's visibility visible.